# How to add identifier column using lead in days in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas table:

```
name date_time
jon  10/01/2019
jon  11/01/2019
jon  12/01/2019
jon  25/01/2019
sam  03/04/2019
sam  18/04/2019
sam  19/04/2019
sam  29/04/2019
fred 02/02/2019
fred 03/02/2019
fred 12/02/2019
fred 13/02/2019
```

Column types in pandas are - name is string and date_time is datetime64[ns, UTC] format

I would like to create a new column which allows me identify if the user was in one "session" or another "session" based on the dates that each user appeared in the data.

A "session" is the first 10 days from which the user first logged a date_time value, anything after those first 10 days is another "session".

It does not mean a new identifier every 10 days, it means only 2 identifiers need to be made - one for the first 10 days from the first date_time value and one from the 11th day onward.

I would like to make these session values to be unique and relative to the name of the person - i'll probably use some string concatenation to get it done but it should be like this:

for example it should look something like this:

```
name date_time  session_identifier
jon  10/01/2019 jon_session_1_id
jon  11/01/2019 jon_session_1_id
jon  12/01/2019 jon_session_1_id
jon  25/01/2019 jon_session_2_id
sam  03/04/2019 sam_session_1_id
sam  18/04/2019 sam_session_2_id
sam  19/04/2019 sam_session_2_id
sam  29/04/2019 sam_session_2_id
fred 02/02/2019 fred_session_1_id
fred 03/02/2019 fred_session_1_id
fred 12/02/2019 fred_session_2_id
fred 13/02/2019 fred_session_2_id
```

As you can see taking the first example of the user jon:

I want to create a identifier (i called it jon_session_1_id) here and this is repeated for the 10 day period from the first date_time value taken - which is 10/01/2019 so the jon_session_1_id will be repeated as the session_identifier up until 20/01/2019 then it will change to be jon_session_2_id.

Each session_id is relative to the person's name.

How can this be done in Python? I understand that it should really be a case when/switch statement based on using a lead function - but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find cumulative difference and apply `lambda`. Example code is as follows

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name' : ('jon','jon','jon','jon','sam','sam','sam','sam','fred','fred','fred','fred'),
    'date_time' : [datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y') for d in ('10/01/2019', '11/01/2019', '12/01/2019', '25/01/2019', '03/04/2019', '18/04/2019', '19/04/2019', '29/04/2019', '02/02/2019', '03/02/2019', '12/02/2019', '13/02/2019')]
})
df = df[['name', 'date_time']]
df = df.sort_values(['name', 'date_time'])
df['diffs'] = df.groupby(['name'])['date_time'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().dt.days)
df = df.groupby(['name','date_time']).sum().groupby('name').cumsum().reset_index()
df['session_identifier'] = df.apply(lambda row : row['name'] + '_session_' + str(2 if row['diffs'] > 10 else 1) + '_id', axis=1)
df
```

output is

```
    name    date_time   diffs   session_identifier
0   fred    2019-02-02  0.0     fred_session_1_id
1   fred    2019-02-03  1.0     fred_session_1_id
2   fred    2019-02-12  10.0    fred_session_1_id
3   fred    2019-02-13  11.0    fred_session_2_id
4   jon     2019-01-10  0.0     jon_session_1_id
5   jon     2019-01-11  1.0     jon_session_1_id
6   jon     2019-01-12  2.0     jon_session_1_id
7   jon     2019-01-25  15.0    jon_session_2_id
8   sam     2019-04-03  0.0     sam_session_1_id
9   sam     2019-04-18  15.0    sam_session_2_id
10  sam     2019-04-19  16.0    sam_session_2_id
11  sam     2019-04-29  26.0    sam_session_2_id
```

Comment: This actually does not answer my question - you are taking the cumulative difference - I am looking to make an anchor point in the dates as the minimum date that has occured and calculating the date difference of these instead

Comment: minimum date for each person or one singe minimum date for entire persons ?

Comment: One single minimum for each entire person - so grouping by name - say Jon - his minimum date is 2019-01-10, the first identifier - jon_session_1_id should basically run from 2019-01-10 to 2019-01-20 - then job_session_2_id would be running from 2019-01-21 onwards - does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with some steps to keep the track of the calculation.

First you can create a column initated as the min date value by user, and a "duration" column doing the diff between the "current date" (current row) and the min date by user column.

Once this column is created you can basically create another one juste checking if the "duration" is lower than 10 it is 0, 1 otherwise.

Then you can concatenate what you want as string output.

Comment: Thanks for breaking down the steps - I will have a crack at it and post some code once I am able to solve it - should be quick!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`GroupBy.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) method:

```
def assign_session(group):
    ix = group.iloc[0,0]
    diffs = [ix + "_session_" + str(1) + "_id" if (group.iloc[i,1] - group.iloc[0,1]).days <= 10  else ix + "_session_" + str(2) + "_id" for i in range(len(group))]
    group.insert(2, "session_identifier", diffs)
    return group

df = df.groupby('name').apply(assign_session)
```

It applies `assign_session(...)` to the whole dataframe in single groups divided by name. The output of this is:

```
    name            date_time session_identifier
0    jon  2019-01-10 00:00:00   jon_session_1_id
1    jon  2019-01-11 00:00:00   jon_session_1_id
2    jon  2019-01-12 00:00:00   jon_session_1_id
3    jon  2019-01-25 00:00:00   jon_session_2_id
4    sam  2019-04-03 00:00:00   sam_session_1_id
5    sam  2019-04-18 00:00:00   sam_session_2_id
6    sam  2019-04-19 00:00:00   sam_session_2_id
7    sam  2019-04-29 00:00:00   sam_session_2_id
8   fred  2019-02-02 00:00:00  fred_session_1_id
9   fred  2019-02-03 00:00:00  fred_session_1_id
10  fred  2019-02-12 00:00:00  fred_session_2_id
11  fred  2019-02-13 00:00:00  fred_session_2_id
```